# Selenium does not react on alert

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-scraping, automation

Chrome version: 80.0.3987.149
Selenium version: 3.141.0

The idea behind program is to open new window with video, collect information from confirmation box (automatically appears when window is opened) and accept the confirmation. Problem is that program hangs when new window appears.

I don't get any particular error, program just continues executing and does nothing. Url is not helpful in this case, so here are pictures of these windows: [main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rkrpg.png), where I click on the link and [window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHDq6.png) with the video and confirmation box.

```
try:
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'VOD')]").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    continue

main_handle = browser.current_window_handle

for handle in browser.window_handles:
    if handle != main_handle:
        browser.switch_to.window(handle)
        print('I switched to: %s' % (browser.current_window_handle)) # this line is not printed

try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present())
    alert = browser.switch_to.alert
    alert_text = alert.text
    alert.accept()
except Exception as e:
    print('Exception: ', e)
```

Comment: Which line is showing the error and can you please share the error message.

Comment: if posssible then can you please provide your url ?

Comment: if you provide entire code snippet then would be helpful dont know how to navigate to your desired page or else try to increase WebDriverWait(browser, 20) just to check it should not happened due to NotFoundException